# I'm doing a tut, but I cant understand this syntax

Tags: php, procedural-programming

I normally write oop code, thats probrably why I never saw this way of coding. I dont understand the syntax in the multidemensional array below, why is `[$obj->id]['label']` not just `$obj['id']['label']]`

```
$sql = "SELECT id, label, link_url, parent_id FROM dyn_menu ORDER BY parent_id, id ASC";
$items = mysql_query($sql);
while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($items)) {
    if ($obj->parent_id == 0) {
        $parent_menu[$obj->id]['label'] = $obj->label;
        $parent_menu[$obj->id]['link'] = $obj->link_url;
    } else {
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['parent'] = $obj->parent_id;
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['label'] = $obj->label;
        $sub_menu[$obj->id]['link'] = $obj->link_url;
        if (!isset($parent_menu[$obj->parent_id]['count'])) {
            $parent_menu[$obj->parent_id]['count'] = 0;
        }
        $parent_menu[$obj->parent_id]['count']++;
    }
}
mysql_free_result($items);
```

Comment: Its a way of dynamically access any array key. THe value of `$obj->id` is used to access the array key.

Comment: I thought you understood OOP? $obj is an object.

Comment: (obligatory comment about mysql_*) - [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and [are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the red box? Learn about [prepared statements](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB)

Comment: Neither `[$obj->id]['label']` or `$obj['id']['label']]` are valid syntax - what are you asking here?

Comment: @Eric he's referring to this bit: `$sub_menu[$obj->id]['label']`

Comment: @Eric: Well, actually, `[$obj->id]['label']` is valid in PHP 5.4 and later :P

Comment: @minitech: Really? I'd expect PHP to impose arbitrary rules about initializing and indexing an array in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

It's because [mysql_fetch_object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) fetches a result row as an object. Others, such as [mysql_fetch_array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), fetch a result row as an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

There are different values:

`$obj->id` has a value, its referencing a value. if you just write 'id' you are referencing the key 'id' (as a string)

Imagine you have an obj with the property id setted as 341.

and this array:

```
$sub_menu = array(
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'Blog',
        'label' => 'My Blog'
    ),
    341 => array(
        'name' => 'Downloads',
        'label' => 'Downloads'
    ),
    'id' => array(
        'name' => 'Tutorials',
        'label' => 'Tutorials Awesome!'
    )
);
```

So when you call the array:

`$sub_menu[$obj->id]['label']` then you are actually calling:
`$sub_menu[341]['label']`
Which is equals to 'Downloads';

If you call
`$sub_menu['id']['label']` then you are calling the sub menu with the key 'id'.
Which is equals to 'Tutorials Awesome!'

Answer (score 0):

`[$obj->id]['label']` and `$obj['id']['label']` aren't even close to the same thing.

`$parent_menu[$obj->id]['label']` gets the value with the `'label'` key from the value with the `$obj->id` key in `$parent_menu`. `$obj['id']['label']` gets the value with the `'label'` key from the value with the `'id'` key in the `$obj` array (which is not an array).

Array keys and properties are not interchangeable in PHP as they are in, say, JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

```
$parent_menu[$obj->id]['label'] = $obj->label;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$myID = $obj->id;
$parent_menu[$myID]['label'] = $obj->label;
```

The operation is that the value of `$obj`'s class property `id` is retrieved and used as the index in the `$parent_menu` array.